# How would I pass data from on screen to another in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am having trouble trying to pass some data to another screen. Currently using the `useState` hook and I would like to use the value on the next screen.

NumScreen.JS:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TextInput, Button, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

function NumScreen({ navigation }) {

  const [num, setNum] = useState("0");


  const pressHandler1 = () => {
    navigation.navigate("CalcScreen", { num });
  }



  const Separator = () => (
    <View style={styles.separator} />
  );


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Enter Number of People:</Text>
      <TextInput
        returnKeyType="done"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="e.g. 3"
        onChangeText={(val) => setNum(val)}
      />
      <Text> Number: {num} </Text>

      <Separator />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pressHandler1}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>Submit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

    </View>
  );
}

export default NumScreen;
```

I want to get the **num** value to the next screen, I tried sending the value using `navigation.navigate` then tried to use getParam but this did not work.

```xml
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, TextInput, Button, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";


function CalcScreen({ navigation }) {
    const [tot, setTot] = useState("0");
    const ppl = navigation.getParam(num);


    const Separator = () => (
        <View style={styles.separator} />
    );

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> num: {ppl} </Text>
      <Text>Enter Total Amount:</Text>
      <TextInput
        returnKeyType="done"
        keyboardType="numeric"
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="e.g. 5.50"
        onChangeText={(val1) => setTot(val1)}
      />
      <Text> Total: {tot} </Text>
      </View>
    );
}

export default CalcScreen;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try using state management libraries like `redux`.

Comment: Where does `navigation.navigate` comes from? I presume react-navigation v5, but you didn't tag it. I've used it and never encountered issue with the params, did you read their doc?

Comment: In react navigation 5, navigation doesn't contain passed params.

Answer (score 0):

When the routing between Screens happens, then you can get the **num** value in the `CalcScreen` component by the following code:

```js
function CalcScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const { num } = route.params;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate function from First Screen. Using :

   this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })
2. Read the params in your Second screen. Using:

   this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)

here is the complete working example, [link](https://snack.expo.io/@asad_4561/00dccb?&preview=true&platform=ios&iframeId=sfrhwj59wh&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Using **props**
We use props to pass data from one class to another or from one page to another in react native.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/props